# Do both lsmod and /proc/modules use the same mechanism to retrieve modules?

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-module

I can get a list of modules using either `lsmod` or `cat /proc/modules`. Do the two approaches use the same mechanism to retrieve the modules? I want to know this as we could use it to find some hidden malicious modules.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are both reading the same kernel interface to produce the list. However, a rootkit may alter lsmod to hide modules but there are myriad ways to read /proc/modules that would be near impossible for a rootkit to modify all of them.

If you're doing something programatic it doesn't really matter which one you use, but lsmod is much more human readable.

**Update**: To include examples.

```
cat /proc/modules
more /proc/modules
less /proc/modules
view /proc/modules
uniq /proc/moduels
uniq < /proc/modules
grep . /proc/modules
grep . < /proc/modules
awk '{print}' /proc/modules
awk '{print}' < /proc/modules
sed 's/(.)/$1/' < /proc/modules
echo "$(</proc/modules)"
perl -p -e ";" < /proc/modules
nc -l 11111 & nc localhost 11111 < /proc/modules
```

Etc., etc., etc. Anything that can read text can display the contents. These are just a few that I thought of in under a minute. If I thought about it I could come up with some *really* esoteric ways.

Comment: `"there are myriad ways to read /proc/modules"` could you please elaborate more on that?

Comment: I'm not sure if you get notified that I edited my answer to include examples, but I did.

Answer (score 1):

If the rootkit works at the kernel level (as a module for instance), you can not rely on the info provided by `/proc/modules`. Furthermore, you can not rely on `lsmod` either as it pretty-prints `/proc/modules`.

Answer (score 1):

We could look up the source code, but if you are lazy like me:

```
sudo strace lsmod |& grep -E '(proc|sys)'
```

Shows interesting hits such as:

```
open("/proc/modules", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/sys/module/ipt_MASQUERADE/refcnt", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
```

so we may guess that most of the info comes from `/proc/modules` and `/sys/module/*`.